# How many horsepower does a 159cc engine have?

Tags: engine

[This device](http://www.chippersdirect.com/Cub-Cadet-CSV050-Chipper-Shredder/p7250.html) has a "159cc Cub Cadet OHV Engine."

Approximately how many horsepower would that have?  I'm comparison-shopping and I'd like to know if this is more or less powerful than a Lawn Machines unit that has a 4.5 HP engine.  Thanks

Comment: This would be a question that a direct contact to the manufacturer is needed for. It's probably not likely that Cub Cadet makes the engine, it's likely merely rebranded from a major manufacturer. Cub Cadet doesn't even think it's of importance when you go to their page for the CSV-050 http://www.cubcadet.com/equipment/cubcadet/csv050 Engine is an MTD Products IP70C0

Comment: In part, horsepower ratings have largely been discounted in small engines. B&S will only tell you a gross torque rating for new ones. and that does not represent the actual engine you get, but an engine without an intake or exhaust. Actual engine values will be lower... https://www.briggsandstratton.com/na/en_us/support/faqs/browse/engine-horsepower-or-torque-value.html

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [questions about small motors are off-topic](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1455/55930)

Answer (score 4):

The cubic centimeter displacement spec of the engine does not directly specify the horsepower. There are other factors such as compression ratio, spark timing and operational RPM at which the horsepower is measured.

You really need to look closely at the engine name plate to see if it specifies the horsepower or contact the manufacturer for details.